UBUNTU 24.04 LTS: Audio devices not available after upgrade from 22.04
After upgrade to 24.04.01 LTS no audio device was available (neither speaker nor mic).
I tried some debug with:
sudo dmesg | grep -i alsa
sudo dmesg | grep -i snd
lspci | grep -i audio
aplay -l

And:
$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio
Unit pulseaudio.service could not be found

(It is ok, 24.04 uses pipewire)
systemctl --user status pipewire-pulse
systemctl --user status  wireplumber

Everything was ok.
There was a problem here:
$ systemctl --user status pipewire    
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-10-05 11:34:35 CEST; 37min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 2784 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 18964)
     Memory: 836.0K (peak: 1.9M)
        CPU: 27ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─2784 /usr/bin/pipewire

Started pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service.
 pipewire[2784]: pw.context: 0x59a5decefaf0: **no modules loaded from context.modules**


the problem is solved, I shared the info for someone else that could have a similar problem

I discovered that actual pipewire configuration files are in  /usr/share/pipewire/
but there was an older pipewire.conf from previous installation in /etc/pipewire that are loaded first:
I renamed this file and after reboot the problem was solved.
